# Product Information Doesn't Show Until I Click Save in Magento

Tags: products, backend, frontend, placeholder

Products on my site show placeholder image and no product information (price, description etc) until I look them up in Magento and click "save". This works even if I don't change any information at all for the products.

I have about 6k products and most don't show until I do this. Please help!

Comment: rebuild your indexes

Answer (score 1):

You can try to select 20 products via category/products and then actions --> update attribute --> website (tab on left side) --> check assign to website box and then save. This should make the items appear on the front end. Also as suggested by Marius, indexing does help and refreshing the cache as well.